# What happened to Sisulizer?

Tags: delphi, localization, internationalization

We have been using Sisulizer localization tools many years. Recently I have noticed that their website is down and even the emails don’t go through. Does anybody know what is going on?

Comment: This kind of question is better suited to a forum like [Delphi-Praxis](https://en.delphipraxis.net)

Comment: Having said that, they appear to have moved to: https://the-localization-tool.com, but have not updated their Facebook or Twitter info about what their website is, and appear to have been inactive for 2 years. I strongly suggest using something else

Comment: @DaveNottage Far as I can tell Delphi-Praxis is not reliably approving new users so probably not a good forum to recommend anymore.

Comment: [sisulizer.de still served a functional website on 2021-09-19](https://web.archive.org/web/20210919140437/https://www.sisulizer.de/), along with phone number and address in the imprint.

Comment: Thank you. I just checked www.sisulizer.de and it gives the same Account Suspended errors as .com and .net. I guess I need to start looking for a new localization tool.

Comment: @Brian - There has been a problem with registrations on en.DelphiPraxis.net which now should be fixed.

Comment: In @Chris's defence, I often feel that SO and the developer community wound benefit from relaxed rules that would allow questions like this. (The rules were much more relaxed a few years ago.) But of course I agree that this Q doesn't fit the current SO guidelines.

Comment: Chris, take a look at Soluling, https://www.soluling.com. It is similar to Sisulizer, but actively developed and supported.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, one of the authors/maintainer of Sisulizer has passed away. Full story here: https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/6000-what-happened-to-sisulizer/

P.S. The DP registration issue has been rectified.